# Perl getting referrer website

Tags: perl, refer

I need some help to get the websites from which I got referrer

```
my $refer = $ENV{HTTP_REFERER}; = google.com/sdaasd
my $website = dont know what how; = google.com 
if ($website eq google.com || $website eq yahoo.com) { do this } 
else 
{ do that }
```

(the website is www.google.com)

All I wanna get is just www.google.com not all link google.com/sdadgasyd

Answer (score 5):

So you want to extract part of a URI?

Start by [searching for that on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/search?q=uri). This leads to the [`URI` module and its documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/URI).

The documentation shows how to instantiate an instance with a URI in a string (which you have), and points out the `host` method which will extract it from the URI.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.16;
use strict;
use warnings;
use URI;

my $uri = URI->new('http://google.com/sdaasd');
say $uri->host;
```

Obviously you won't get `www.google.com` when the input is `google.com` because they are different hostnames.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
my $refer = $ENV{HTTP_REFERER};

if(index($refer, "google.com") || index($refer, "yahoo.com") {
  #do this
} else {
  #do that 
}
```

Comment: `my $refer = "http://example.com/mirror/google.com/"`

Comment: hehe, i realized it too after posting the answer :)